# Excel VBA Evaluate and non-integer arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I've written this function:

```
Function Resolveq(Equacao As String, Variavel As String, Valor As Double) As Double
    Resolveq = Evaluate(Replace(Equacao, Variavel, Valor))
End Function
```

and tested it with:

- the expression (passed to Equacao) `25*EXP(-x/100)`
- the variable (Variavel) `x`
- the values `18` and `18.25`

With the value `18` (or any other integer) the expression is calculated correctly; with `18.25` (or any other non-integer value) Excel returns a `#Value!` error.

But calculating the same expression with the expression written in a cell, it goes well, with integer and non-integer values.

Can someone, please, give me a light here?

Comment: Hi Paulo, welcome to SO. Can you put an example of the call you would use in the post, please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the parameters of the Replace function are not being used correctly. They are:

```
Replace (string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )
```

The replacement parameter is expecting a string and you are passing a Double.

Convert the Double to a string before you pass it to the function.

```
Function Resolveq(Equacao As String, Variavel As String, Valor As Double) As Double
Dim ValourStr as String
ValourStr = CStr(Valor)
Resolveq = Evaluate(Replace(Equacao, Variavel, ValourStr))
End Function
```

Comment: VBA will convert to string anyway without the explicit conversion.

Comment: It certainly should but the code worked fine for me for all values when I forced the conversion first.

Comment: I didn't try it without! Perhaps there's no error at all!

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help in my first question here. The problem was simple and I just have to blame myself for beeing stupid: as I am in Portugal, my Excel (and all Office apps) work with a comma (and not a point) as decimal separator. That was all! :))

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Sub test()
Dim var As Variant
var = Resolveq("25*EXP(-x/100)", "x", 18.25)
End Sub
```

And this entered in a cell also works for me

```
=Resolveq("25*EXP(-x/100)", "x", 18.25)
```